# VLOOKUP Function for a list of items to return one value - EXCEL VERSION 2016

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup, excel-2016

I am practicing excel functions and I am trying to learn how to make a sheet of data require the least amount of manual entry. I have an excel sheet of information regarding sales transactions and I am trying to use VLOOKUPs to automate most of the data entry and I am stuck with one particular task.

I have two kind of appliance categories: MDA and SDA (medium and small domestic appliances) and a list of appliances that fall underneath these two categories

[image: screenshot of columns referred to]

in the screenshot inserted above, it classifies the items/appliances into the two categories using the columns by placing a check mark of the items fall under the category or not.

I wanted to automate the categorizing using the checkmarks by using a VLOOKUP function

I listed the items in a separate table in a different sheet where:

MDA includes:
PDC, PRF, PLC, PCG
and SDA includes: PCP

however I struggled to form the VLOOKUP so I thought to use an IF function however I don't know how to phrase it where I could state that IF the cell contains PDC OR PRF OR PLC OR PCG place a tick in the MDA column ELSE IF it contains any of those AND PCP place a tick in both the MDA and SDA columns ELSE if it only contains PCP to place a tick in the SDA column ELSE leave the cell blank

is that possible at all?

Comment: The problem with your logic - "IF the cell contains PDC OR PRF OR PLC OR PCG...", this means that your second test "ELSE IF it contains any of those AND PCP" will never be used. The only way your second test can be true is if your first test was already true.

Comment: what should I do then? how would I form the logic correctly?

Comment: I think you probably just want to treat them as 2 separate columns with 2 separate tests. For the MDA column, if the item contains PDC, PRF, PLC, or PCG, put a tick in the MDA column, regardless of whether it contains PCP. Separate logic for the SDA column, if the item contains PCP, put a tick in the SDA column, regardless of whether it contains anything else. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, and Scott Craner corrected my logic and showed me a functioning solution as well. thank you for the help!

Comment: Ah I didn't see the answer a few minutes ago, I think because it was being edited. I see he's got it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use SEARCH to see if they exist or not.

For the MDA

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({",PDC,",",PRF,",",PLC,",",PCG,"},","&SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","")&","))),"√","")
```

For the SDA

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",PCP,",","&SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","")&",")),"√","")
```

[image]

Comment: it gives me an error: this value does not match the data validation restrictions defined for this cell

Comment: Remove the data validations on the cells.

Comment: I removed the validations and the formula got accepted however it returns blank cells

Comment: Then your data is not what you are showing.  as you can see it works in my example.

Comment: I removed the empty double quotes for when the value is false and it returned a cell with the word false, so it seems to assume the condition is false for some reason even though I copied your code exactly

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?  This only works in Office 365 version.

Comment: I have the 2016 version

Comment: Then that is why you only get `FALSE`

Comment: You may want to edit your post with the version and platform so others may help.

Comment: then what would be an adequate solution for the 2016 version?